# CSS table span hover inheritance

Tags: html, css, inheritance, html-table, hover

Trying to understand what is going on, maybe someone can explain.
Upon `:HOVER` I want the entire table content to go transparent. This works for text inside `td` wrappers. However, text inside a `span` wrapper doesn't know it should go transparent.

If I remove `color:#897` from the `span` CSS suddenly it does what I want and all text goes transparent. I did try all sorts of CSS tricks to no avail, the table refuses to recognize `span` as a descendant of `table`. What is wrong and how to fix it, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you define color in `SPAN` as `table#Factors span` & you define your hover `table#Factors:hover` So `color` of `SPAN` still override you `table#Factors:hover` class color. Write like this:

```
table#Factors:hover span{
  color:transparent;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/AyNg3/

Read this for more http://diythemes.com/thesis/css-specificity-thesis/

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xja7z/)

```
table:hover,
table:hover span{
    color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
}​
```

You just needed to include a selector for the `span` as well.